# Passing List of records with jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I've a situation where I want to pass list of records via Ajax/JQuery.

```
public JsonResult GetListOfRecords()
{
   return Json(_repository.GetAllRecords());
}
```

when I call this action method with jQuery, it doesn't work:

```
$.getJSON('GetAllRecords', function(data){ // data is IQueryable<T> or IEnumerabel<T>
$.each(data, function(d) {
    $('#somewhere').html(d.Title); //d is SomeModelType and Title is property of that type
});
});
```

Note: GetAllRecords method returns **IQueryable**.... I also tested **IEnumerable**

However, if pass **ArrayList** type, it seems to be work (but not fulfill my need):

```
public JsonResult GetAllRecords()
{
  var list = new ArrayList();
  foreach(var item in _repository.GetAllRecords())
  {
    list.Add(item.Title);
  }
  return Json(list);
}
```

it just displays title...

My Question is that "I want to pass **IQueryable** or **IEnumerable** through ajax."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be the case. The following works perfectly fine with an `IEnumerable<T>` and an anonymous type:

```
public ActionResult GetListOfRecords()
{
    return Json(
        Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Select(i => new
        {
            Id = i,
            Title = "title " + i
        }),
        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
    );
}
```

and to invoke:

```
$.getJSON('<%= Url.Action("GetListOfRecords") %>', { }, function(records) {
    $.each(records, function(index, record) {
        alert(record.Id + ' ' + record.Title);
    });
});
```

Also notice the slight subtility in the [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function.

In your case you have:

```
$.each(data, function(d) { ...
```

In my case I have:

```
$.each(data, function(index, d) { ...
```

The first parameter of the callback is the index, not the value.

Comment: OIC...in the jQuery i doesn't used index parameter...It may work now...thanks